# the color for the default selected row of the UIpickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, color-picker

I have a CityPickerView which has 2 components for user to select the Chinese city.I want the color of the selected row is red and the unselected row is gay, meanwhile, the background color of pickerView is white.

I have completed the major function,but when run the app,the color of the **default- selected row** isn't red. **How to solve it ?**

When user select the row of the component 0,the data of the component 1 will reload automatically,and the first row of the component 1 is selected. Both of the  row of the component 0 and the first row of the component 1 is red color.

But when user select the 3rd (or more) row of the component 1,then select another row of the component 0.The selected row of the component 0 is red,but the first row of the component 1 is not red,it is still gay color. **How can I solve it ?**

And, if user select the row of the component 1 directly ,**how to make the the row of the component 0 is also red color ?**

**The codes for the UIPickerViewDelegate is following:**

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSUserDefaults  *pickerSelectionDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pickerSelectionDefaults setInteger:row forKey:@"leftComponentSelectionKey"];
    [pickerSelectionDefaults setInteger:row forKey:@"rightComponentSelectionKey"];
    [pickerSelectionDefaults synchronize];

    UILabel *labelSelected = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
    [labelSelected setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];


    if (component==0) {
        [pickerView reloadComponent:1];//if any row of the component 0 is selected,then reload the data of the component 1
        [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];//if the row of the component 0 is selected,then set the first  row of the component 1  is selected
        UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:0 forComponent:1];//get the label of the row 0 of component 1
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    [self changeTextField];

}
```

**and**

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel *label = (id)view;

    if (!label){

      label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
      label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
      pickerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
      label.text=[self pickerView:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];
      label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    }
    return label;
}
```

If you need more detail info.,I'll give it here.Thanks.

Comment: You want the red color only for selected row?

Comment: And grey color for unselected rows?

Comment: yeah,I have done it.

Comment: So you don't need any answer?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I need help with this issue.Another issue is that if I select the 3rd or 4th or ……(if the 1st or 2nd ,no this issue)row of the component 1,and then select the row of the  component 0.Only the selected row of the  component 0 is red, but the 1st row of the component is still gay color,I want  it is also red color.

Comment: There is a UITextField on the UI, when user click the textField,the cityPickerView needs to display. And the 1st  rows  of the  component 0 and  component 1 are red color.the other rows are gay.

Comment: The first issue: I want the row 0 of component 0 and component 1 are red color(other rows is gay color) when the CityPickerView is displayed  on UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color by using this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    //On Selecting the component row
    if (component == 0) {
    } else if (component == 1) {
        [quantityPickerDelegate didChangeLabelText:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];// delegate passing the selected value
        [pickerView reloadComponent:component]; //This will cause your viewForComp to hit
    }
}
- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    pickerLabel.textColor = defaultColor;
    if([self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component] == row) //this is the selected one, change its color
    {
        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0745 green:0.357 blue:1.0 alpha:1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have  seen the codes before. I use another way to set the color for the  selected row.

Comment: Do u have an email？ I send u the screenshot.Maybe the picture can describe the issue well.

Comment: Hi, I  have sent u an email  for the detailed issue

Comment: Hi, I haven't received any email.

Comment: I checked the email  which I sent was shivanisethi6383@gmail.com. Right ?

Comment: I will  send it once more, and  the subject is ' issue on UIPickerView '

Comment: Got It. I will check.

Comment: So you want to change the color of first picker?

Comment: first picker means? The demands are in the mail I have sent to you.

Answer (score 0):

'animated' parameter should be ‘false’

eg)
‘pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: comp, animated: false)’

If it’s ’true’, it will take some time for the picker to eventually get to the row you manually selected
and color change could be ignored by the delay